# Nested lists or any other structure? c#

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

I am doing a quiz type game and I am trying to decide the best structure to handle it.

10 or more questions, each one will have multiple answers, all wrong but one.

The user will choose the right one from 4 visible answers (radio buttons) randomly picked up from the list. It will be assured that the right answer is always picked up.

The list will have multiple sub-lists inside (each one a question and multiple answers)

In those sub-lists the first position[0] will be the question, all the rest[1...] will be the answers.

My question is, nested lists are proper way of doing this? Am I thinking this right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about a `List<Question>`, where `Question` is a class you defined to have the answers (*being something like `.A`, `.B`, `.C`, and `.D`*) if it's always going to be 4 answers. Otherwise if the answers aren't a fixed amount it can have a List/Array of answers. Note SO is for programming problems/questions where there is something wrong with the code or ask about specific functionality, for working code and suggestions on the best way to do it check out [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I would probably make a class.

```
public class Question {
   public string TheQuestion;
   public string[] TheAnswers; //first should be correct answer
   public Question(string quest, string[] ans){
      TheQuestion = quest;
      TheAnswers = ans;
   }
}
```

Then you could make a `List<Question> Questions` of all the questions you like and pull from them. When setting up the answers always let the first array value be the correct answer and you could then randomize the order to show the answers.

```
List<Question> Questions = new List<Question>();
string q = "Is stackoverflow the best?";
string[] a = new string {"Yes!", "No.", "Probably Not" };
Question q1 = new Question(q, a);
Questions.Add(q1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Binding Purposes and etc., I suggest using a list of custom classes; such as:

```
var questionList = new List<QandA>();

///...

public class QandA
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer1 { get; set; }
    public string Answer2 { get; set; }
    public string Answer3 { get; set; }
    public string Answer4 { get; set; }
    internal int CorrectIndex { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers here, however I would likeley organize things a bit different.  Rather than making answer 1 always the correct.  You can lay it out like I did below to offer a little bit more flexibility in randomizing the multiple choice and making it easier to compare if the answer was correct.

```
// core class
    public static class Quiz
    {
        private static Random rnd = new Random();
        public static Question[] Questions = new[]
        {
            new Question
            {
                QuestionText = "Sample uestion 1?",
                CorrectAnswer = "Answer to question 1",
                WrongAnswers = new [] {
                    "Wrong answer 1",
                    "Wrong answer 2",
                    "Wrong answer 3",
                    "Wrong answer 4",
                    "Wrong answer 5",
                }
            },
            new Question
            {
                QuestionText = "Sample uestion 2?",
                CorrectAnswer = "Answer to question 2",
                WrongAnswers = new [] {
                    "Wrong answer 1",
                    "Wrong answer 2",
                    "Wrong answer 3",
                    "Wrong answer 4",
                    "Wrong answer 5",
                }
            }
        };

        public class Question
        {
            public string QuestionText { get; set; }
            public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
            public string[] WrongAnswers { get; set; }

            public string[] GetMultipleChoice(int numberOfChoices)
            {
                var list = new List<string>() { CorrectAnswer };
                list.AddRange(WrongAnswers.Take(numberOfChoices - 1));

                // shuffle
                int n = list.Count;
                while (n > 1)
                {
                    n--;
                    int k = rnd.Next(n + 1);
                    var value = list[k];
                    list[k] = list[n];
                    list[n] = value;
                }

                return list.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    // console application
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var question in Quiz.Questions)
        {
            // write question
            Console.WriteLine(question.QuestionText);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, question.GetMultipleChoice(4)));

            var response = Console.ReadLine();

            if (response.Equals(question.CorrectAnswer, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A "List of Lists" can work, but may be very limiting. You would not have many opportunities to organize the logic of your program.

Rather, you should probably create classes to represent the "things" in your model. Look for the important nouns: Quiz, Question, and Answer.

```
class Quiz {
   List<Question> mQuestions = new List<Question>();

   // implement functionality that is relevant at the Quiz level
}

class Question {
   string mQuestionText;
   List<Answer> mAnswers = new List<Answer>();       

   // implement functionality that is relevant at the Question level
}

class Answer {
   string mAnswerText;
   bool mIsCorrect;

   // implement functionality that is relevant at the Answer level
}
```